# Start slide with URL

Tags: slider, url-routing

I need to go to slide 5 by URL.
So when I type url.com/#slide5 or something like /?start=slide5 
 the code "startSlide: 5," needs to be triggered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 300,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 3,
    startSlide: 5,
    slideMargin: 10
  });
});
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Are you using  any server side language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [window.location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;

  $('.slider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 300,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 3,
    startSlide: hash,
    slideMargin: 10
  });
});
```

But for this you will have to add only slide number to the hash e.g. url.com/#5 or apply some logic to strip slide number from the hash.

Comment: Should beware as hash sometimes return '#' the hash symbol as well. Use window.location.hash.substring(1) to get only the numerical value.